# How to make a change value on a mock with a static method?

Tags: mockito

I have this code:

```
    Request r = mock(Request.class);
    ClassUtils.calculate(r);
```

The method calculate(r) changes the value of the request:

```
public static String calculate(Request r){
     r.setVlaue(...);
     ...
}
```

Since r is a mock in my test, how do I do so that its value changes when I use the static method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, many ways lead to Rome...

If you only want to be sure that `r.setValue(...)` was actually called, for example with "xyz", you can use `verify`:

```
Mockito.verify( r, Mockito.times(1) ).setValue( "xyz" );
```

Of course you can also store the value in an answer, for example...

```
Mockito.when(r.setValue( Mockito.any() ).thenAnswer( new Answer<Void>() {

     public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
           String value = invocation.getArguments()[0];
           ...do something with the value...
     }

});
```

For this, there is also a simpler option, again using `verify`...

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Mockito.verify( r, Mockito.times(1) ).setValue( captor.capture() );
String value = captor.getValue();
```

But perhaps the most obvious question is: Are you sure that you need a mock? Perhaps a simple fake object (simply override/implement that class yourself) might do the trick as easily as any mock?